# Rhythm Tengoku The Best Plus, how to get to 100 "Nori-kan"?

Tags: rhythm-game, rhythm-tengoku-the-best-+

So, I'm currently at 88 "nori-kan". I'm not sure the badges would give me this "nori-kan", but even if they did, I would be at 96 "nori-kan". The wiki said something about there being 100 mini-games, but even if they did, I already have the "Play all of the mini-games" and the "Get all of the mini-games to High Level rank" badges.

So how can I get 100 "nori-kan"?

Comment: how do you know that 100 "Nori-kan" is possible?

Comment: Because there are apparently over 100 games. Each game awards 1 nori-kan for completion. But here's the catch: there AREN'T 100 games. And I've seen 100 nori-kan before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It has been said to be impossible](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q11147390121) for most ordinary people. [Basically, it is not related to having badges and you must have an average score of 100](http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q10147592285) on all the 104 mini-games.

It also appears to round up, in the case of [this guy who has a total score of 10162](http://citruslemon.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/12/30/121759), which when divided by 104 gives 97.7 but he has 98 nori-kan. Since 100 is the perfect score, that means you need to have a perfect score of 100 on at least 52/104 of the mini-games and 99 on the other 52/104.

Comment: Wow, someone ACTUALLY responded after, like, I dunno, 2 years? THANK YOU!

Comment: @Luiyay You're welcomed :) there wasn't much information in English so I was searching in Japanese.